# Shifted Neumann series expansion validity?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be any matrix. Is it true  that if $m \in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $|m|\cdot||A||<1$, then $$A^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nm^{n+1}(A-\frac{1}{m}I)^n\,,$$
or is it false? I just substituted $A=B+I \frac{1}{m}$ in the original Neumann  series saying that

$$(B+I\frac{1}{m})^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nm^{n+1}B^n\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nm^{n+1}\left(A-\frac{1}{m}I\right)^n$ ever converges, it is straightforward to verify that $AS=I$ and hence $S=A^{-1}$. The only question is whether the infinite series converges or not. Since this can be rewritten as a Neumann series in $B$, we know that it doesn't always converge. Convergence is guaranteed when $\|mB\|=\|mA-I\|<1$, but the series may diverge otherwise. For instance, let $A=-\epsilon I$ for some $\epsilon>0$, so that $A^{-1}$ always exists. However, when $\epsilon$ is small and $m=1$, we have $\|mA\|=\epsilon\|I\|<1$ but
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nm^{n+1}\left(A-\frac{1}{m}I\right)^n
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1+\epsilon)^nI
$$
doesn't converge.

Comment: Thank you. How did you verify that $AS=I$?  Also, can I then say that for any matrix $A$, there exists an $m \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $||mA-I||<1$, and so I can express its inverse as above for that choice of $m$?

Comment: Actually no, I guess this is not the case for all matrices $A$...If $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$, there is no $m$ such that $(I-mA)$ is convergent I guess..

Comment: @pulosky (1) If an infinite series converges, its $n$-th term must approach zero when $n\to\infty$. In our case, this means $\lim_{n\to\infty}(I-mA)^n=0$. Now, if $S_k$ denotes the partial sum up to $n=k$, direct calculation shows that $AS_k = I-(I-mA)^{k+1}$. Let $k\to\infty$, we get $AS=I$. (2) Yes, your counterexample works.